# JsonConvert does not deserialize object properly

Tags: c#

I have this simply follow json and class that I want to DeserializeObject to object.

```
{"UnsubscribeResponse": {
   "txId": "123",
   "result": "Success",
   "message": "OK"
}}

public class UnsubscribeResponse
{
    public string  TxId { get; set; }

    public string Result { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I've just tried to use those following approaches but anyone of them work for me.

```
unsubscribeResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<UnsubscribeResponse>();


unsubscribeResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UnsubscribeResponse>(contents, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                         ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Auto
});
```

The only way that it worked I had to use the JObject class like below:

```
var resp = JObject.Parse(contents).SelectToken("UnsubscribeResponse");
```

Anyone already had this issue and can help me?

Answer (score 6):

Add a new class:

```
public class UnsubscribeResponsewrapper
{
    public UnsubscribeResponse UnsubscribeResponse { get; set; }
}
```

and then rather than reading / deserialising as `UnsubscribeResponse`, use `UnsubscribeResponseWrapper` instead. This is necessary since your JSON is:

```
{"UnsubscribeResponse": {
   "txId": "123",
   "result": "Success",
   "message": "OK"
}}
```

For your *original* code to work, the JSON would need to be something like:

```
{
   "txId": "123",
   "result": "Success",
   "message": "OK"
}
```

You need the extra class since your JSON has the `UnsubscribeResponse` property. I suspect you are looking at your JSON and thinking *this is a `UnsubscribeResponse` object and its properties*. **But that isn't actually what your JSON is.** It is *this is an object, with a `UnsubscribeResponse` property (and that property has a set of its own properties)*. As such, you need to either alter the JSON (as per my altered JSON) or alter the code (as per my class).