# JSON.NET Case Insensitive Deserialization not working

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I need to deserialize some JSON into my object where the casing of the JSON is unknown/inconsistent. JSON.NET is supposed to be case insensitive but it not working for me.

My class definition:

```
public class MyRootNode
{
    public string Action {get;set;}
    public MyData Data {get;set;}
}

public class MyData
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

The JSON I receive has `Action` & `Data` in lowercase and has the correct casing for `MyRootNode`.

I'm using this to deserialize:

```
MyRootNode ResponseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyRootnode>(JsonString);
```

It returns to be an initialised `MyRootNode` but the `Action` and `Data` properties are null.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Added JSON

```
{
   "MyRootNode":{
      "action":"PACT",
      "myData":{
         "name":"jimmy"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the JSON?

Comment: @Guy I added the JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JsonConvert does not deserialize object properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384033/jsonconvert-does-not-deserialize-object-properly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an additional class:

```
public class MyRootNodeWrapper
{
    public MyRootNode MyRootNode {get;set;}
}
```

and then use:

```
MyRootNodeWrapperResponseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyRootNodeWrapper>(JsonString);
```

*https://stackoverflow.com/a/45384366/34092 may be worth a read. It is basically the same scenario.*

Also, change:

```
public MyData Data {get;set;}
```

to:

```
public MyData MyData {get;set;}
```

as per advice from @demo and @Guy .

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: @CathalMF You should also change `Data` property to `MyData`, `public MyData MyData { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 27):

This is the .NET Core built-in JSON library.

I found another way of doing it.. just in case, somebody is still looking for a cleaner way of doing it. Assume there exists a `Movie` class

```
    using System.Text.Json;
```

.
.
.

```
    var movies = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
        <IEnumerable<Movie>>(responseStream,
        new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        });
```

#### Startup Options:

You can also configure at the time of application startup using the below extension method.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(
                x =>
                {
                    x.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
                });
    }
```

Comment: Startup Options didn't work for me :(, I'm using dot net 6.

Answer (score 5):

Simply add   `JsonProperty` attribute and set jsonProperty name

```
public class MyRootNode
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "action")]
    public string Action {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "myData")]
    public MyData Data {get;set;}
}

public class MyData
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

---

UPD: and yes, add some base type as @mjwills suggest

Comment: Adding the JsonProperty is hardcoding the required casing. The point is the the people supplying the JSON are not consistent with their casing. Sometimes they are upper case, then lower case, then a mix. I hate this 3rd party. haha

Comment: So `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "myData")]` is the key line here @demo ? Nice spotting BTW!