# Mapping issue when Deserialising

Tags: c#, json, case-insensitive, system.text.json

I have the following code:

```
    using System.Text.Json;
    private async Task<AuditReviewerDelegationDto> GetDelegationAsync()
    {
        // TODO: Get current logged in user, pass mdmuseridentifier
        var mdmUserIdentifier = 248113;
        var response = LocalHttpClient.GetAsync(BaseAddress + "api/AuditReviewerDelegation/GetDelegation/" + mdmUserIdentifier).Result;

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var tt = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AuditReviewerDelegationDto>(responseContent);
        return tt;
    }
```

My variable responseContent has all the data that I expect. However, when I use the Deserialize method, my tt variable is empty. I believe the reason for this is that all the properties on the responseContent start with a lower case, but on my AuditReviewerDelegationDto they all start upper case. I cant change my model to be lowercase. Is there anyway I can either get the deserializer to ignore case or set the response object to retun camel case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON.NET Case Insensitive Deserialization not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782127/json-net-case-insensitive-deserialization-not-working) Please [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.propertynamecaseinsensitive?view=net-5.0) that for more information.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] including your class definitions and full JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in order to ignore the casing of your property names, you just need to set `JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive` to `true`. See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-casing) for more details, but here's what that might look like in code:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
};
var tt = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AuditReviewerDelegationDto>(responseContent, options);
```

However, if `tt` itself is `null` (rather than the individual properties of `tt` being `null`) you might have another problem - it depends on the actual text within `responseContent`.