# Deserialize nested json objects into c# objects

Tags: c#, json

I have the following Json response:

```
{
  "Customers": [
    {
      "Customer": {
        "Address": {
          "City": "Stockholm",
          "PostalCode": "10123"
        },
        "Classifications": [
          "LoyaltyProgram",
          "Returning",
          "VeryImportant"
        ],
        "FirstName": "Peter",
        "LastName": "Centers",
        "Passport": {
          "Expiration": "2019-01-14",
          "Number": "1564931321655"
        },
      },
      "FirstName": "Peter",
      "LastName": "Centers",
      "Reservation": {
        "AdultCount": 2,
        "AssignedSpaceId": "03f59360-8644-4e29-927a-ad85a6514466",
      },
      "RoomNumber": "302"
    },
  ]
}
```

I have the following classes for every Customer:

```
public class CustomerDto
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<string> Classifications { get; set; }
    public PassportDto Passport { get; set; }
    public AddressDto Address { get; set; }
}

public class AddressDto
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}

public class PassportDto
{
    public string Expiration { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

from this I use Json.Net and the following code from one of my methods (extract) where customers below is the response:

```
var jsonCustomers = JObject.Parse(customers)["Customers"].Children().ToList();
IList<CustomerDto> customerList = new List<CustomerDto>();
foreach (var item in jsonCustomers) {
    customerList.Add(item.ToObject<CustomerDto>());
}
```

All the values in CustomerDto are filled except for Address and Passport, that are null, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add two new classes:

```
public class CustomersWrapper
{
    public IEnumerable<CustomerWrapper> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerWrapper
{
    public CustomerDto Customer { get; set; }
}
```

and then replace all of your existing code with:

```
        var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomersWrapper>(input);
        var customerList = results.Customers.Select(z => z.Customer).ToList();
```

*This will ensure that standard deserialisation occurs for all objects in the hierarchy.*

This is needed due to the odd structure of your JSON. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45384366/34092 is the same basic issue (and may be worth a read) - essentially you shouldn't really have `Customers` and `Customer` in your JSON. Without those, you wouldn't need the two wrapper classes I have specified.

*You may also wish to avoid specifying `FirstName` and `LastName` twice (unnecessarily) in the JSON.*

Comment: Yes, I'm not taking care of the outer values of FirstName and LastName, just getting the "Customers".

Comment: Yes, it worked just perfectly, thanks. :) The Json response comes from another source/company (an online hotel booking system) where I have no control over the code. I agree that the Json response looks a bit odd, and when asked about it they said it looks like this due to backward compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a class which has a list of customers on it:

```
public class CustomerList
{
    public IList<CustomerDto> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

And the to deserialize the object just call:

```
CustomerList jsonCustomers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerList>(customers);
IList<CustomerDto> customerList = jsonCustomers.Customers;
```

Edit:
Didn't notice Customer was a nested property on the list of objects in the json array so need another class wrapping the `CustomerDto`. @mjwills has posted the full answer.

Comment: This is a nice code sample, however doesn't solve the problem that was asked. Adding this code, will still produce Address and Pasport set to Nothing (Null).

Comment: Yes, just realised that I missed something with the structure of the json and  @mjwills has updated their answer with the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `AddressDto` and `PassportDto` will not be deserialized, just because you are deserializing at one level up in your JSON graph.

Write a class like:

```
public class WrapCustomer
{
        public CustomerDto Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize this in your for-loop:

```
customerList.Add(item.ToObject<WrapCustomer>());
```

Now you will see everything is populated as you expected.